# Turn EJB into JSON web service

Tags: java, web-services, json, ejb

I have turn EJB 3.1 into web-service. And now I need to create the JSON webservice for communication with JavaScript component. JavaScri[t component will use JSON version of the interface to communicate with the system and fetch the data needed. I can not use XML instead of JSON by the performance reason. I tried research myself but any solution was not found.

Please, have you any ideas, solutions or links how I can use EJB and JSON together.

Thanks!
Best regards
Artem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, [JAX-RS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAX-RS) is meant to do that - to let you expose RESTful services. Popular implementations are [RestEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy) and [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/). They will in turn delegate to a JSON processor like [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/).

You can use Jackson alone, but you'll have to manage many things manually. If you want to use SOAP with JSON (which is not the common choice), then check JAX-WS and the [JSON Extension](http://jax-ws-commons.java.net/json/)

Comment: Hi, thanks to advance. Could you please say, may be you know the way to realize SOAP + EJB + JSON? Would be happy in your help. Thanks!

Comment: ah, so you need SOAP to use JSON, rather than rest? Check http://jax-ws-commons.java.net/json/

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [Restlet](http://www.restlet.org/) which is nicely designed, and solves most of the REST concerns (content-type negotiation, method routing, authentication, form handling...) for you. If you bump into problems, authors are quite responsive on their e-mail list.