# Android communication with EJB server

Tags: android, json, web-services, jboss, ejb

Android has a built in library for JSON and I was wandering if anyone has any experiences on EJB with JBoss backend. Is there possible to integrate a session bean with a web service sending and receiving JSON objects to and from an Android client. Where would you start?
I couldn't foun

The intent is to have the clients and server periodically send information to each other.

Are there other options for this kind of connection? We have started the logic of the server and we want to stay on using EJB with web services. Alternatives are welcome as well, I would ask thought if it scales well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turn EJB into JSON web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994976/turn-ejb-into-json-web-service)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of JBoss are you using?

In JEE6 (JBoss 7) you have JAX-RS that allow you easily back restful ws with EJB and it can consume and produce JSON.

You can look at the JEE6 tutorial ( http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepu.html ) and JBoss implementation RESTEasy that you can use with older version of JBoss ( https://www.jboss.org/resteasy ).

For JAX-RS integration with EJB you can look here: [Inject an EJB into JAX-RS (RESTful service)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027834/inject-a-ejb-into-jax-rs-restfull-service)